# Kindly explain to me what this script does

Tags: scripts

Can someone kindly explain to me what this script does? I am a newbie to scripting language.

```
if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
declare -x CONFIG_FILE_DIR=$1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is a bash script, it says

- if the script is called with a single command-line argeument; then
- assign the value of that argument to the variable `CONFIG_FILE_DIR` and export it

Exporting makes the variable visible to child shells (otherwise, variables have local scope) - type `help declare` at the bash shell prompt for more details about the usage and options of the `declare` built-in.

Comment: Steeldriver, Thank you very much for the prompt response.Does it mean that $# means " calling the script with arguments?"

Comment: What if I want to change the file to  not take any arguments, how do i change this script? Let say i wanted to pass it a file path called ./x/b, what exactly does the "$1" hold?

Comment: `$#` expands to the **number** of positional parameters (command line arguments) that the script was called with. `[ $# -eq 1 ]` **tests** that value for equality against the decimal integer `1`. If you call the script with `./x/b` as its first (or only) argument, then `$1` will expand to the string `./x/b`

Comment: Perfectly understood.Thanks a million steeldriver!

Comment: Since we are on a roll, do you by any chance know how I can execute  a bash script in eclipse and give this relative file part ./a/b as the input argument. In terminal I will just invoke the script and give it the argument as #./startme.bash (this is the file which uses the path name as input) ./x.b

Comment: I saw your other question (about eclipse) but I'm not sure I can answer it. FYI as a matter of good practice, you should quote the variable expansion `CONFIG_FILE_DIR="$1"` - that way, it won't fail if you pass a filename with a space in it.